# Understanding Optimizely API

Tags: javascript, api, optimizely

I am trying to understand better how the optimizely api works. I am a newbie. So please excuse me if I am asking something very obvious.

But I thought the API works by using an optimizely object that has two methods get and push, and a data object. But then I saw this code on the optimizely site that appears to be assigning t**he variable windows[optimizely] to an array [ ]. Shouldn't it be { } and not [ 
]**. Please help

```
var activated = function(event) {
// The Optimizely snippet has been activated.
var visitorId = window.optimizely.get('visitor_id').randomId;
console.log("The visitor ID is: " + visitorId);
};

window["optimizely"] = window["optimizely"] || []; 
// SHOULDN"T THE ABOVE BE **window["optimizely"] = window["optimizely"] || {}
window["optimizely"].push({
type: "addListener",
filter: {
  type: "lifecycle",
  name: "activated"
},
// Add the activated function as a handler.
handler: activated
});

window["optimizely"].push(['trackEvent', 'watchedVideo']);
```

Answer (score 5):

(The below is referring to the Optimizely X snippet JS API.)

For those seeking to interact with the Optimizely snippet's API, there are two phases of execution to keep in mind:

1. **Pre-initialization:** The time *before* the Optimizely snippet is evaluated by the browser. Most folks have the `<script>` tag in the `<head>` of the document, and it is evaluated synchronously. In this case, all the JS code appearing above the `script` tag is the code that falls in this phase.
2. **Post-initialization:** The time *after* the Optimizely snippet is evaluated. For the common case described above, this is everything below the `script` tag. nit: This is actually a simplification; the JS API is actually available slightly earlier, during the *initialized* lifecycle hook onward.

In some cases, one wants to "pre-push" or enqueue calls to the API, before Optimizely has initialized (i.e., during phase 1 above). At that time, you can write JS that sets `window.optimizely` to an array of API calls (each of which is an object).

During initial evaluation, the Optimizely snippet consumes any pre-pushed API calls present in the `window.optimizely` array (if it exists), and then assigns to `window.optimizely` the object that has the `get` function that's documented throughout the docs. As a result, code that's evaluated post-initialization should expect to interact with the initialized API, `optimizely.get(...)`.

It's also worth highlighting that the means of making API calls in **both** phases superficially resemble one another: the pre-init option is an array, so has a `push` method; the API object that's available post-init *also* has a `push` method. They both take the same parameter: an object defining an API call.

In the example you gave, an API call to register with the `activated` lifecycle hook is pre-pushed to the `window.optimizely` array of pre-pushed API calls. When the browser evaluates the snippet, it will execute any such calls.

Please let me know if that makes sense or not!

source: I work at Optimizely on the team that owns the snippet.

Comment: That's helpful and clever. Looks like google analytics uses the same trick. Right? 

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);  

I understand the need for push in pre-init now. But in the post-init phase why use push function. Why not simply use get function to read data from the local data objects

Comment: I think having a common interface for interacting events is easier to manage. Why document two syntaxes when one works in all cases?

Comment: Great explanation, Wilson! Now it makes sense :)